# Angular 5 Omitting .0 from from 1.0 from an API response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, httpresponse

In Angular 5, I am getting an API response as 1.0. But while populating to the html field it is displaying as 1.

In the chrome dev-tools, under Network tab->**Response** it is showing as 1.0 but under Network Tab -> **Preview** it is shown as 1.

I tried mapping the response to a model in angular, But none worked.

```
 response is : 
    {
        amount: 1.0,
        quantity : 3.0,
        id: "20184563251",
    }


this.result = reportResponse.body;
this.cartForm.patchValue(
    {
        'inputTextField': this.result.amount, // While patching only 1 is patched
     });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).It will return a string

```
this.rateData.amount.toFixed(1)
```

Comment: If I use toFixed(1), if the amount consists of more than 1 decimal, only one digit is getting displayed. Ex: 2.46 is displayed as 2.5. But we want to display as 2.46

Comment: Just put a condition before passing it through `toFixed`

Answer (score 1):

It is consideting it as the number, better convert it to string first

```
this.result = reportResponse.body;
this.cartForm.patchValue(
    {
        'inputTextField': String( this.rateData.amount), // convert it to string
     });
```